# Extracting HTML data using Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

There are several HTML tables I am trying to extract data between the `<td>` from.

The HTML structure for each table is looks like this

```
<td rowspan="2" class="nfvtTitleTop"><b>Delta</b></td></tr><tr><td class="nfvtTitleSTop">USD <span style="color:#808080"><i>(in Million)<i></span></td><td class="nfvtTitleSTop">%</td><td class="nfvtTitleSTop">USD <span style="color:#808080"><i>(in Million)<i></span></td><td class="nfvtTitleSTop">%</td></tr><tr><td class="nfvtTitleLeft">More Personal Computing</td><td class="nfvtR">42,276</td><td class="nfvtR"><i>38.4%</i></td><td class="nfvtR">45,698</td><td class="nfvtR"><i>36.4%</i></td><td class="nfvtR"> <span class='cPos'>+8.09%<span></td></tr><tr><td class="nfvtTitleLeft">Productivity and Business Processes</td><td class="nfvtR">35,865</td><td class="nfvtR"><i>32.6%</i></td><td class="nfvtR">41,160</td><td class="nfvtR"><i>32.8%</i></td><td class="nfvtR"> <span class='cPos'>+14.76%<span></td></tr><tr><td class="nfvtTitleLeft">Intelligent Cloud</td><td class="nfvtR">32,219</td><td class="nfvtR"><i>29.2%</i></td><td class="nfvtR">38,985</td><td class="nfvtR"><i>31.1%</i></td><td class="nfvtR"> <span class='cPos'>+21%<span></td></tr></table>
```

As you can see the data is nested inside of a larger table. Because of this I am having trouble on how I can extract it. Below is what I have tried so far

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(html).content, 'html.parser')
data_all = {}

for table in soup.select("table.tabElemNoBor overfH fvtDiv"):
    for tr in table.select('tr'):
        row = [td.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for td in tr.select('td')]
        data_all[tr].append(row)
print(data_all)
```

This just returns a blank set of {}

Here is the url: https://www.marketscreener.com/MICROSOFT-CORPORATION-4835/company/

I am trying to scrape the data tables on this page if possible. After trying out Aramakus suggestion, this is returning the headers of the tables. So perhaps it is not the  tags that I require!

Here is an image of one of the tables. 
[image]

I did an inspect element on the figures and they appear to be between  tags. But when I did something like

```
for elem in soup.find_all("td"):
    print(elem)
```

EDIT:

Thanks all for the help. I seem to be getting there. If I do

```
for elem in soup.find_all("td", {"class" : "nfvtR"}):
    print(elem)
```

This seems to return the individual figures. But can I make it so that I return the whole table?

Any help?

Comment: try with a "." between class names: "table.tabElemNoBor.overfH.fvtDiv"

Comment: @BendikKnapstad Thanks for the response. I just tried this and it gives me the following:     data_all[tr].append(row)
KeyError: <tr><td>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tabTitleWhite">
<tr><td class="tabTitleLeftWhite"><nobr><b>Sales per Business</b></nobr></td></tr>
</table>
</td><!-- inner td --></tr>

Comment: Use ‘select(‘.tabElemNoBor’)’

Comment: @0m3r Thanks for the reply. It also gave me the same thing

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you have in variables. Maybe server sends you different HTML then you expect (or which you can see in Web Browser) or it sends warning for bots or captcha. OR maybe page use JavaScript to add elements - `requests`/`BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript

Comment: I'm not really too sure how to do that. I'm quite new to all of this.

Comment: simply display  `requests.get(html).content` or save it in file and open in any text editor or even in web browser to see what you get. BTW: servers may send different HTML for different devices (phone, tablet, desktop) and you may need correct header `User-Agent` in `requests.get()`

Comment: code works for me with this URL if I use dots in `select("table.tabElemNoBor.overfH.fvtDiv"):` (because it is correct CSS select for many classes) and if I use `data_all[tr] = row`. If you don't get result then check what you get in HTML - maybe server blocks your script and send warning or captcha.

Comment: the biggest problem is that there are nested tables and some tables have nested columns - so different tables need different code. Some of them need more complex code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code gives me all data and save in CSV. I had to get only nested tables to make it simpler.

Problem is that tables `Sales per Business`, `Sales per region`, `Equities` have nested columns and it gives less headers then columns and it creates incorrect CSV file. You have to add headers befor saving files to create correct CSV.

For `Sales per Business`, `Sales per region` headers are in two rows so I join them using `zip()` (and using `del` to remove second row)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = 'https://www.marketscreener.com/MICROSOFT-CORPORATION-4835/company/'

r = requests.get(url) #, headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

all_tables = []

for table in soup.select("table table.nfvtTab"):
    table_rows = []
    for tr in table.select('tr'):
        row = []
        for td in tr.select('td'):
            #print(td)
            item = td.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')
            #print(item)
            row.append(item)
        table_rows.append(row)
    all_tables.append(table_rows)

# add headers for nested columns

#Sales per Business     
all_tables[0][0].insert(2, '2018')
all_tables[0][0].insert(4, '2019')
all_tables[0][1].insert(0, '')
all_tables[0][1].insert(5, '')

# create one row with headers
headers = [f'{a} {b}'.strip() for a,b in zip(all_tables[0][0], all_tables[0][1])]
print('new:', headers)
all_tables[0][0] = headers  # set new headers in first row
del all_tables[0][1]        # remove second row

#Sales  per region
all_tables[1][0].insert(2, '2018')
all_tables[1][0].insert(4, '2019')
all_tables[1][1].insert(0, '')
all_tables[1][1].insert(5, '')

# create one row with headers
headers = [f'{a} {b}'.strip() for a,b in zip(all_tables[1][0], all_tables[1][1])]
print('new:', headers)
all_tables[1][0] = headers  # set new headers in first row
del all_tables[1][1]        # remove second row

#Equities
all_tables[3][0].insert(4, 'Free-Float %')
all_tables[3][0].insert(6, 'Company-owned shares %')

for number, table in enumerate(all_tables, 1):
    print('---', number, '---')
    for row in table:
        print(row)

for number, table in enumerate(all_tables, 1):
    with open(f'table{number}.csv', 'w') as f:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
        csv_writer.writerows(table)
```

Result:

```
new: ['', '2018 USD (in Million)', '2018 %', '2019 USD (in Million)', '2019 %', 'Delta']
new: ['', '2018 USD (in Million)', '2018 %', '2019 USD (in Million)', '2019 %', 'Delta']
--- 1 ---
['', '2018 USD (in Million)', '2018 %', '2019 USD (in Million)', '2019 %', 'Delta']
['More Personal Computing', '42,276', '38.4%', '45,698', '36.4%', '+8.09%']
['Productivity and Business Processes', '35,865', '32.6%', '41,160', '32.8%', '+14.76%']
['Intelligent Cloud', '32,219', '29.2%', '38,985', '31.1%', '+21%']
--- 2 ---
['', '2018 USD (in Million)', '2018 %', '2019 USD (in Million)', '2019 %', 'Delta']
['United States', '55,926', '50.8%', '64,199', '51.2%', '+14.79%']
['Other Countries', '54,434', '49.4%', '61,644', '49.1%', '+13.25%']
--- 3 ---
['Name', 'Age', 'Since', 'Title']
['Satya Nadella', '52', '2014', 'Chief Executive Officer & Non-Independent Director']
['Bradford Smith', '60', '2015', 'President & Chief Legal Officer']
['John Thompson', '69', '2014', 'Independent Chairman']
['Kirk Koenigsbauer', '51', '2020', 'COO & VP-Experiences & Devices Group']
['Amy E. Hood', '47', '2013', 'Chief Financial Officer & Executive Vice President']
['James Kevin Scott', '54', '-', 'Chief Technology Officer & Executive VP']
['John W. Stanton', '64', '2014', 'Independent Director']
['Teri L. List-Stoll', '57', '2014', 'Independent Director']
['Charles Scharf', '53', '2014', 'Independent Director']
['Sandra E. Peterson', '60', '2015', 'Independent Director']
--- 4 ---
['', 'Vote', 'Quantity', 'Free-Float', 'Free-Float %', 'Company-owned shares', 'Company-owned shares %', 'Total Float']
['Stock A', '1', '7,583,440,247', '7,475,252,172', '98.6%', '0', '0.0%', '98.6%']
--- 5 ---
['Name', 'Equities', '%']
['The Vanguard Group, Inc.', '603,109,511', '7.95%']
['Capital Research & Management Co.', '556,573,400', '7.34%']
['SSgA Funds Management, Inc.', '314,771,248', '4.15%']
['Fidelity Management & Research Co.', '221,883,722', '2.93%']
['BlackRock Fund Advisors', '183,455,207', '2.42%']
['T. Rowe Price Associates, Inc. (Investment Management)', '172,056,401', '2.27%']
['Capital Research & Management Co. (World Investors)', '139,116,236', '1.83%']
['Putnam LLC', '121,797,960', '1.61%']
['Geode Capital Management LLC', '115,684,966', '1.53%']
['Capital Research & Management Co. (International Investors)', '103,523,946', '1.37%']
```

---

Code which I used to test CSV files:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(f'table1.csv', index_col=0) #, header=[0,1])
print(df)

df = pd.read_csv(f'table2.csv', index_col=0) #, header=[0,1])
print(df)

df = pd.read_csv(f'table3.csv') #, index_col=0)
print(df)

df = pd.read_csv(f'table4.csv', index_col=0)
print(df)

df = pd.read_csv(f'table5.csv') #, index_col=0)
print(df)
```

Comment: Amazing thanks! Wouldn't have figured out how to deal with the nested columns!

Comment: I changed little code to connect two rows with headers. And I tested result using `pandas`

Answer (score 0):

Don't mean to change your mind about beautiful soup, it is a great tool... But I am personally opinionated that Python has a much more elegant built in solution in [htmlparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) module.

Here's how you'd solve this using htmlparser.

```
ipstr = """
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tabElemNoBor overfH fvtDiv"><tr><td>
    <table class="tabTitleWhite" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr><td class="tabTitleLeftWhite"><nobr><b>Sales per Business</b></nobr></td></tr>
    </table>
</td><!-- inner td --></tr>
<tr><td class="std_txt th_inner  center" style="padding-top:4px"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="nfvtTab">
      <colgroup>
       <col width="40%">
       <col width="15%">
      </colgroup>
     <tr><td rowspan="2" style="border:0px"></td><td colspan="2" class="nfvtTitleTop"><b>2019</b></td>
     """

from html.parser import HTMLParser

class ExtractDataFromBTag(HTMLParser):
def __init__(self):
    HTMLParser.__init__(self)
    self.found_b = False

def handle_starttag(self,tag,attr):
    if tag == "b":
        self.found_b = True

def handle_data(self,data):
    if self.found_b == True:
        print(data) ### or do whatever you want with it. like assign it to an attribute of your object

def handle_endtag(self,tag):
    if tag == "b":
        self.found_b = False
eg = ExtractDataFromBTag()

eg.feed(ipstr)
```

[Check out the PyFiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/d64a59ad-82ff-48e3-8455-dc144dff035e/?i=true)

Answer (score 0):

*Try*

```
select('.tabElemNoBor b')
```

*Example*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tabElemNoBor overfH fvtDiv"><tr><td>
    <table class="tabTitleWhite" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr><td class="tabTitleLeftWhite"><nobr><b>Sales per Business</b></nobr></td></tr>
    </table>
</td><!-- inner td --></tr>
<tr><td class="std_txt th_inner  center" style="padding-top:4px"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="nfvtTab">
      <colgroup>
       <col width="40%">
       <col width="15%">
      </colgroup>
<tr><td rowspan="2" style="border:0px"></td><td colspan="2" class="nfvtTitleTop"><b>2019</b></td>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for elem in soup.select('.tabElemNoBor b'):
    print(elem.text)
```

*should print*

> ```
> Sales per Business
> 2019
> ```